# Excel issue- After changing the formula, the cell will become a pure text cell

Tags: excel

I am using Excel 2016, and I am facing an issue that I never met before.

When I input any formula to a cell, it works what it should be. But once I want to change/edit the formula in the cell, the cell will turn into pure text cell. No matter how I empty the cell and redo the formula, the same problem just won't go away. The only solution I found is replacing the broken cell with an unused cell.

What's wrong?

Comment: Hi. Can you post your forumula. Are you sure you are using the equals symbol? Does it happen with all the formulas you enter, or just this specific one?